# Como alinhar os itens com display grid?

Tags: css, grid, svelte

Estou criando um site e o layout é feito com **display grid** e está parte de criar o layout já entendi perfeitamente, porém não consigo fazer com que meu header por exemplo tenha o efeito do ***justify-content: space-betweeen***, ou ***centralizar*** o conteudo de uma div, section, etc.

Fiz um codigo para exemplificar (uso svelte).

````
<script>
    const iconM = 'src/assets/letra-m.png'
   
</script>
<div class="__layout">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src={iconMarkana} alt="Markana logo"></a>
            <div class="navbar-supported-content">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/">Registro de Marca</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/">A Empresa</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/">Beneficios</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/">Dúvidas</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/">Contato</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/">Fale pelo Whatsapp</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="box1">
        <div class="__layout">
            <div class="content1"><p>Texto 1</p></div>
            <div class="content2"><p>Texto 2</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
        <div class="__layout">
            <div class="content3"><p>Texto 3</p></div>
            <div class="content4"><p>Texto 4</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box3">
        <div class="__layout">
            <div class="content5"><p>Texto 5</p></div>
            <div class="content6"><p>Texto 6</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box4">
        <div class="__layout">
            <div class="content3"><p>Texto 7</p></div>
            <div class="content4"><p>Texto 8</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<style>
    .__layout {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-gap: 5px;
        grid-template-areas: 
        "Header Header"
        "box1 box2"
        "box3 box4"
    }


    header {
        grid-area: Header;
    }

    .navbar {
        grid-area: Header;
        height: 80px;
        display: flex;        
        padding: 3px;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        display: flex;
        height: 50px; 
        width: 50px;
    }

    .navbar-supported-content{
        grid-area: Header;
        display: flex;
        align-items: right;
        justify-content: space-between;

    }

    .navbar-nav {
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-right: 25px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .box1 {
        background: red;
        grid-area: box1;
        border: 1px solid;
    }

    .box2 {
        background: blue;
        grid-area: box2;
        border: 1px solid;
    }

    .box3 {
        background: green;
        grid-area: box3;
        border: 1px solid;  
    }

    .box4 {
        background: yellow;
        grid-area: box4;
        border: 1px solid;   
    }

    .content1 {
        border: 1px solid;
        justify-items: center;
    }

    .content2 {
        border: 1px solid;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .content3 {
        border: 1px solid;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .content4 {
        border: 1px solid;
        align-content: center;
    }

    .content5 {
        border: 1px solid;
        place-items: center;
    }

    .content6 {
        border: 1px solid;
        place-content: center;
    }

</style>```

Nada que eu faça move o conteudo dentro das divs (o TEXTO em si)
````

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro vc precisa fazer com que a regra `.navbar-nav` use 100% do espaço horizontal disponível com um `width: 100%`:

```css
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 100%; /* adicione esse atributo */
}
```

Segundo, vc precisa fazer também com que `.navbar-supported-content` ocupe 100% da largura com um `width: 100%;`

```css
.navbar-supported-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: right;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%; /* adicione esse atributo */
}
```

Note que eu também removi o atributo `grid-area: Header;` porque ele só tem efeito nos elementos que estão imediatamente dentro de um elemento c/ atributo `display: grid`. Sub-elementos não tem efeito neste caso.